# How do you select all records from a mongodb collection in golang using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

In MongoDB doing something like `db.mycollection.find()` returns all documents in a collection.

When working in GoLang using the package **labix.org/v2/mgo** and I do for example:

```
query := db.C("client").Find();
```

It complains that it requires input in the form of an interface. All I need to do is retrieve all documents and iterate through them and display each one for now. How do I achieve this effect? All examples I have seen seem to have filters in place.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
    var results []client

    err := db.C("client").Find(nil).All(&results)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Do something about the error
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Results All: ", results) 
    }
```

Comment: getting nil from a database is a weak reason to `panic`

Comment: however will get the user of the above code to actually read it and decide how to deal with the `nil`. From the perspective of someone coming here and copy/pasting that code being highly likely, this is a good way to get them to at least think about it....

Comment: you can use `db.c("client").Find(bson.M{}).All(&result)`

Answer (score 0):

```
func (uc UserController) GetUsersList(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request,p httprouter.Params){

var u []models.User
// Fetch user
if err := uc.session.DB("mydb").C("users").Find(nil).All(&u); err != nil {

    w.WriteHeader(404)
    fmt.Println("Results All: ", u) 
    return
}
uj, _ := json.Marshal(u)

w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.WriteHeader(200)
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", uj)

}
```